# After moving EE to a new server front-end hangs and never loads

Tags: server-migration, loading-time

Moving EE between QA servers and experiencing an issue. The CP loads right up without issue. Can go straight to the home page as well (which is not managed with EE). However, when going to the `blog` channel (currently the only content we have managed with EE) the page gets stuck loading and never displays any content or errors. The loader in Safari's address bar just stop at about 10% and never loads.

Suggestions on places to look for issues? I've double/triple checked all paths and everything looks correct.

Comment: This looks like a infinite loop on a .htaccess file. Can you, please, update your answer and show the redirect and rewrite rules on this file?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `(domain_name)/index.php` does the page load? If this works I would suggest looking at your .htaccess file (supposing your server runs Apache), making sure it was copied correctly and nothing needs to be changed.

UPDATE: Since you say your page does finally load but after a crazy number of seconds, I recommend you try the following steps to troubleshoot your issue.

1. Install [EE Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/mithra62/ee_debug_toolbar);
2. In the control panel, go to Admin>System Administration>Output and Debugging and turn on "Display Template Debugging?";
3. Reload your front end page (while still logged in to the control panel as super admin);
4. Use EE Debug Toolbar to identify any pain-points. The toolbar will show you the total template rendering time in the fifth box, and query execution time in the last box. Clicking on either will give you more detail.

[EE Debug Toolbar's GitHub readme page](https://github.com/mithra62/ee_debug_toolbar) gives you a high level idea of what the toolbar looks like and how it works.

Try these steps, see if it doesn't point out anything obvious to you, and if you have more symptoms but no answers, update your question so we can troubleshoot further. Best of luck!

Comment: So it just started loading but takes upwards of 45 seconds. When loading with the Network tab open in the inspector I see that "blog" takes at least 98% of the 45 seconds, then all assets (images, css, etc.) take the rest.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more steps you can try, given this new information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change all the server paths? Assuming they differed between the servers.